# Did Yahoo recently discontinue one of their geo web services?

Tags: web-services, yahoo, geocode

I was using a Yahoo web service to resolve zip codes to geo information.  An example url is

http://where.yahooapis.com/geocode?q=35060,mx

where 35060 is the area code and mx is the country.

I am now receiving 404s when I do this.  Did this service change?  I see now that yahoo offers GeoPlanet which requires an application id as well.

Comment: I'm getting the same thing. I haven't found anything to indicate the service was intentionally shut off or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although there doesn't appear to be an official announcement from Yahoo, there have been consistent reports about this service no longer working.

As an "official" alternative, consider Yahoo Placefinder, which requires an app ID and 2-legged OAuth authentication: http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/requests-pf.html

Alternately, you may be able to use YQL to retrieve the information you need without requiring authentication:

http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20geo.placefinder%20where%20postal=%2236050%22%20and%20country=%22mexico%22&diagnostics=true

Comment: I ended up going with google for the meantime but now I am bit hesitant to use a web service.  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?sensor=false&address=10001,US